# Where can I find source code for adb shell top command

Tags: android, linux, shell, adb, android-source

I'm trying to find source code for ***adb shell top*** command so in the future I could monitor data from it without resourceful requests (like ***adb shell dumpsys***).
Through [Android Code Search in platform/superproject](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject) I managed to find reference to this command in [external/toybox/toys/posix/ps.c](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:external/toybox/toys/posix/ps.c)
I'm not familiar with C language and this particular code doesn't have a lot of comments so I'm not sure if it's what I'm looking for.

Comment: If C was the source for the code what do you expect? What are you looking for really, some cheat sheet for top command using via adb shell ?

Comment: @wuseman I'm trying to find a way to monitor CPU and memory of a device so I could log changes that are above a certain percent without a loop of resourceful requests. The closest thing to what I found is adb shell top command. I've also tried to figure out the way to modify ActivityManagerService but because of the lack of documentation for aosp, it's tricky for me to understand how it communicates with other classes.

Comment: @IrinaK does the answer below help in figuring out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the source code you're looking for is inside the [top_common](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/toybox/+/refs/heads/android-s-beta-4/toys/posix/ps.c#1471) function.

In particular you can focus on the following line:

```
if (readfile("/proc/stat", pos = toybuf, sizeof(toybuf)))
```

(and subsequent ones) to get information on the CPU, whereas this one:

```
if (readfile("/proc/meminfo", toybuf+256, sizeof(toybuf)-256))
```

(and subsequent ones) is devoted to read information on the memory.